# Stripe retrieve customer Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, checkout

I want Stripe to check if the customer already exists and if yes associate it to the checkout session.

```
    class OrdersController < ApplicationController

        @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
          payment_method_types: ['card'],
    
          shipping_address_collection: {
            allowed_countries: ['GB']
          },
          customer_email: current_user.email,
    
          line_items: line_items_order,
    
          success_url: new_order_message_url(@order),
          cancel_url: order_url(@order)
        )
    
        if @user.stripe_id != nil
           Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripe_id)
           @session.customer = customer.id
           @session.customer_email =customer.email
    
        else
    
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
          email: current_user.email,
          name: current_user.username,
          metadata: {
          },
        })
    
         @user.stripe_id = customer.id
         @user.save
    
      end


   @order.checkout_session_id = @session.id
   @order.save
  end
```

I checked with byebug and saw that Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripe_id) is working, Stripe API is able to find te right customer, but still create a new customer for each checkout session. I have read the documentation about the sessions objetc and found that about the customer attribute:

> customer attribute:
> The ID of the customer for this Session. For Checkout Sessions in payment or subscription mode, Checkout will create a new customer object based on information provided during the payment flow unless an existing customer was provided when the Session was created.

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `Stripe::Checkout::Session.create` without passing in the customer. As mentioned in the doc for customer, it should be passed when creating the session if you want to use an existing customer

> customer string EXPANDABLE
>
> The ID of the customer for this Session. For Checkout Sessions in
> payment or subscription mode, Checkout will create a new customer
> object based on information provided during the payment flow unless an
> existing customer was provided when the Session was created.

So just make sure you have the customer in the create method

```
@session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
  customer: customer.id
  ...
)
```